# Javascript Objects Inside Array - Incorrectly Evaluating

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Why does the code below print "Tree", "Tree", and not "Bear", "Tree"?

```
var file_array = new Array(100);
var fileobject = {name: null , folder: null , url: null , modified: null};

fileobject.name = "Bear";
file_array[0] = fileobject;
fileobject.name = "Tree";
file_array[1] = fileobject;

console.log(file_array[0].name);
console.log(file_array[1].name);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one object involved. Assigning an object value with `=` assigns a **reference** to the object, not a copy.

It's possible to copy objects, but in the general case it can grow to a very hard problem (due to things like reference cycles). If you need lots of those objects, a better solution would be to write a function that returns a fresh object when you call it:

```
function makeFileObject(name) {
  return {name: name , folder: null , url: null , modified: null};
}

file_array[0] = makeFileObject("Bear");
file_array[1] = makeFileObject("Tree");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, been pulling my hair out over this one!